# json key is not sent correctly in ajax request

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, url-rewriting, character-encoding

I'm making a request using $.ajax (jquery). I'm sending a parameters object. However, a particular key is not being encoded properly.

```
var parameters = {
        "sdk":0,
        "hub":"something.es",
        "site":"something.es",
        "section":"replay",
        "slug1":"vod",
        "slug2":"samsung-tv-app",
        "output":"xml_vast2",
        "url":"http://www.something.es",
        "description_url":"http://www.something.es",
        "country":"es",
        "somecms":"i3",
        "player":"i3",
        "vpos":position,
        "sitesection":fromSection,
        "contenttype":"videos",
        "pagename":pageName,
        "title":title
    };
    $.ajax({
        url :         baseURL,
        data :        parameters,
...
```

However, the request looks like this (Look that &section=replay appears as §ion=replay  )

http://analytics.something.com/ads/tagsv2/video/?&sdk=0&hub=zzzzz.es&site=yyy.es§ion=replay&slug1=vod&slug2=samsung-tv-app&output=xml_vast2&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.something.es&description_url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.something.es&country=es&somecms=i3&player=i3&vpos=preroll&sitesection=shows&contenttype=videos&pagename=desfile."

I've made different combinations, using ', ", no quotes and no way. The most funny thing is that if I change the key to 'asection' or even 'Section' (with upper S), it works fine.

What should I do in order to send the key correctly?

Comment: I think the request is going through fine. Did you check the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens, because [`&sect` maps to § in HTML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Section_sign). This shouldn't be a problem for your app internally (as your requests have nothing to do with HTML). If you want to display URLs to the user, escape them.

Comment: the thing is my client don't accept it and requires me to post the parameter s as x=123&section=aaaa&y=4444. How can I encode the key to display it in this way?

Comment: &sect is displayed as § in HTML. It shouldn't have anything to do with your request.